# How can I parallelize this Matrix times Vector operation using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

I try to parallelise the for loop in the below code, but I am not sure of what type of OpenMP directives should I add before the for loop and do I need to declare those variables in private or public first?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <omp.h>

 void mxv_row(int m, int n, double *A, double *B, double *C)
 {
 int i, j;
 # pragma omp parallel private(?)shared (?)
 for (i=0; i<m; i++)
 # pragma omp for
 {
 A[i] = 0.0;
 for (j=0; j<n; j++)
 A[i] += B[i*n+j]*C[j];
 }
 }
```

Comment: As this is written, a compiler should reject it on account of the pragma omp for not being applied to an individual for().  It looks like you mean to place the omp for on the outer loop.  You might wish to assure that the inner loop is optimized with simd reduction, although a compiler might do this automatically if A[] is declared with restrict *A and an option like gcc -ffast-math is set (and j is local as mentioned in the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you declared `j` outside the loop, it should be private. If you declare it in the second `for` loop, it's fine then.

The rest can be shared (except `i`, as it's your parallel loop index), but doesn't have to, as it's only sizes and pointers.